# Symfony2 inherit parent service strange behavior

Tags: symfony

I have a base abstract service that depends on the request from the dependency injection container. Here its definition:

```
services:
    acme.controller.abstract.basic:
        class:    "Acme\CommonBundle\Controller\AbstractBasicController"
        abstract: true
        calls:
            - [setRequest, ["@request"]]
```

Since this service definition requires the request scope, I change my definition to this:

```
services:
    acme.controller.abstract.basic:
        class:    "Acme\CommonBundle\Controller\AbstractBasicController"
        abstract: true
        scope: request
        calls:
            - [setRequest, ["@request"]]
```

Now, I inherit this service definition into a concrete service as follow:

```
services:
    acme.controller.website:
        class:  "Acme\WebsiteBundle\Controller\WebsiteController"
        parent: "acme.controller.abstract.basic"
```

But I get an exception saying that `acme.controller.website` has a wider scope than the request object. To fix this, I need to add the `scope: request` to my concrete service. But, I would have thought that the scope definition would have been inherited from the base abstract service so it would not be necessary to re-add the `scope` parameter to my child service.

Is it the intended behavior to disallow inheritance of the `scope` parameter? If yes, maybe you know the reason why it cannot be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it an intended behavior but I don't know the exact reason yet.

```
    // merge in parent definition
    // purposely ignored attributes: scope, abstract, tags
    $def->setClass($parentDef->getClass());
    $def->setArguments($parentDef->getArguments());
    $def->setMethodCalls($parentDef->getMethodCalls());
    $def->setProperties($parentDef->getProperties());
```

Src: [Source code comment](https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection/blob/master/Compiler/ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass.php#L79)

Comment: Thanks for digging. For completeness, [here an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4620) on the github issue tracking of Symfony2 about this exact problem. Upvote but will accept only when I have the answer why :)

Comment: I had same issue, so I had to figure out for my sake. Meanwhile I found your post, so posted here which might help someone :)